# Difference between "это" and "оно"

Tags: грамматика

I am confused when to use это and when to use он.
For example, in the sentence
Я люблю еду. Эта дефект. or
Я люблю еду. Она дефект. or
Я люблю еду. Это дефект.
Я люблю еду. Она(эта) вкусная.
Does это refer to the food of does it refer to the fault?
I want to say I love food. It is a fault or it is delicious.

Comment: I don’t understand your English phrase. What do you mean by “I love food. It is a fault.”? Does it mean a bad habit of yourself, like, you overeat and gain weight? Or that the food is spoiled (then why do you say you love it?)?

Comment: Bob let's clarify what you actually mean so that we can reopen. The phrase "Я люблю еду, она дефект" is completely cryptic for a Russian speaker, and it's impossible to choose between two incomprehensible phrases  and, even more, explain your choice )

Comment: What I mean is I love food. It is a fault because I will gain weight. There is nothing wrong with the food. There is something wrong with me.

Comment: the correct pronoun is **это**, you point at the entire fact, but **недостаток/порок** instead of **дефект**, **дефект** in a person is usually of a physical kind and innate

Comment: Another example 'Я знаю исскусство социалистического реализма а я ненавижу её – эта художество диктатора.' should it be она художество диктатора or это художество диктатора?

Comment: **исскусство** is neuter therefore the correct pronoun is **его**, but when you point at the entire fact the only correct pronoun is **это** like the English **this** or **that**, so **... я ненавижу его - это ...**

Comment: @Bob Daley In pattern you use, always Это, never Эта, Этот or Эти. Always Это. Here is right versions for your examples: 1) Я люблю еду. Это дефект.  2) Я люблю еду. Она дефект. 3) Я люблю еду. Она вкусная. 4) Я люблю еду. Это вкусно. I just don't understand why you say [I love] when [food is fault]. Usually people do not love food, when it is fault (bad food). Я не люблю еду. Она дефективная.

Comment: The food is not at fault, I am. Я люблю еду. Это проблема.

Comment: Use он/она/оно when the object you are talking about is already identified